# Escaping _$ (underscore and dollar sign)

Tags: bash, shell-script, escape-characters

I have this Bash script

```
for i in 1 2 3
do
    for j in 4 5 6
    do
        echo "hello_$i_$j"
    done
done
```

but it prints

hello_4
hello_5
hello_6

three times, whereas (you may guess) I want *hello_1_4*, *hello_1_5*, etc.

Escaping only the underscore or only the dollar sign does not work. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `echo "hello_${i}_${j}"` - for the same reason as here: [Bash nested command substitution not working](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83288/bash-nested-command-substitution-not-working) (the second set of brackets is optional)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add the line: `set -u` to the top of your code. Then rerun and see what you get.

The error that variable `i_` is unbound, meaning not defined anywhere. Now why is bash talking about this variable `i_`? You did not define it anywhere. Look closely at your echo statement: `"hello_$i_$j"` the underscore after the $i is being seen as the variable `i_` since `_` is a valid variable name identifier character.

So to prevent bash from doing so, you need to enclose the variable name in braces `{}`, like as, `echo "Hello_${i}_${j}"` The braces prevent the variable name from spilling over and abutting with the `_`. Note: the braces on variable `$j` are optional as the `"` serves the purpose of delimiting.